# ServiceBus Architecture Pros and Cons

Tags: architecture, service, soa, bus

What are the Pros and Cons of using a Service Bus architecture in a SOA project?

What are the suggested open source Service Bus platforms that you would recommend?

Thanks in advance

Comment: my first inclination on seeing this question was to vote to close, but hey it's an interesting question. +1

Answer (score 3):

pro: loose coupling, stable infrastructure

con: hard troubleshooting and monitoring

Answer (score 1):

I think pros and cons of service bus is related to the requirements in your project. It can be tunned as you want.
You can build your own Service Bus like architecture using JMS and Apache ActiveMQ (as Broker service).

There are JBoss ESB available which is good for enterprise application.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ESB provides high level of abstraction,it must support the functionality (the dynamic behavior) required of the system,also it must conform to the system qualities,
and all implementation details are hidden. 
that's about the pros the cons I don't have an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just like in any other architecture you have pros and cons, but in my experience the positive aspects are way greater.

To start with you don't have a single point of failure, and you get an asyn system, meaning that you will probably use some queue system allowing to have a message durability infrastructure. One of the negative sides of a systems like this and given its nature of being distributed, it is harder to debug or trace messages without the use of other technologies like Splunk.

As for the open source technologies, it really depends, are you more towards the .NET world (Mass Transit), Java (JMS), Javascript (Node).?